# British or Australian live action kids show in the mid 90's

Tags: story-identification, tv, super-hero

I remember catching this show maybe 2-3 times randomly while channel surfing as a kid. That being said, I only have fragments of what I remember.

- I remember that there was a group of kids. Maybe from 12-15 or so in
  age.
- I remember they had the power to teleport either to and from an underground base, or they could teleport freely.
- The setting was in London... or Sydney... I can't remember and it was so long ago, I'm blending the accents they had... I'm pretty sure it was London, tho.
- The group of kids had other powers maybe, I don't recall.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I watched this occasionally as a kid.  It's a UK show called [The Tomorrow People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_People#1990s_series).  It was a remake of an older show of the same name, but the original was quite different from the 90's version.

Comment: Yes, definitely the 90s remake of the Tomorrow People. It had Todd from Neighbours plus a bunch of British kids, hence the mixed accents.

Comment: Oh man I used to watch the original on The Third Eye on Nickleodeon stateside.  I loved that show.