# Story identification mini series about psychic kids

Tags: story-identification, psychic, powers

It's an 8 to 10 year old miniseries there are kids with powers. One kid is kept in a certain machine and the bad guy uses it to influence people.
Only seems I can remember the bad guy is speaking a certain hymn to make someone commit suicide and in another he sits in a car being pulled over by a police officer and is trying to influence him to bring a helicopter to search for some kids.
He twirls his finger like a helicopter to reinforce the suggestion.

As much as I search online I can't find anything referring to that.

Comment: Kid? Boy kid or girl kid? Do you remember whether they were white or black, young or old? Where was the show set, was it futuristic or modern? Aside from telepathy, what other powers did these kids have? How many of them were there? Where (country) did you see this show?

Comment: possibly the same as this post: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/british-or-australian-live-action-kids-show-in-the-mid-90s

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possible answers, one of which might be the one you seek.

The first was a 7-episode 1977 ITV miniseries called [Children of the Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Stones). You can view [full episodes on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWMjegykSSg).  This one sounds more like your description, with the "machine" in question being some sort of beam to a black hole using the power of the standing stones in the title.

The other possibility is another ITV series which ran from 1972-1975, called [The Tomorrow People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People).  It was remade in 1992-1995 and has since appeared again beginning in 2013 in an American version on CW Network.  You can view most of the [original episodes on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qHUS2ytlMs) as well as episodes from the 1990's remake and the new CW version.